# Java Jackson, как десериализовать JSON массив в класс?

Tags: java, serialize, jackson

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Есть JSON:

```
["OBSOLETE_PASSWORD_BEHAVIOUR","TEST"]
```

Есть Java класс, в который нужно десериализовать этот JSON:

```
public static class GetSettingsRequest extends StdDeserializer<GetSettingsRequest> implements IPluginHandlerRequest {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8647274387961994808L;

    private List<String> settingNames;

    protected GetSettingsRequest() {
        super(String[].class);
    }

    @Override
    public GetSettingsRequest deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        GetSettingsRequest result = new GetSettingsRequest();
        result.settingNames = Arrays.asList(p.readValueAs(String[].class));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Вопрос: можно ли это сделать, не используя кастомный десериализатор, как в моём примере? Вроде как записать json массив во вложенный в класс лист, не используя объектную оболочку в самом json?

Answer (score 1):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String[] strings = mapper.readValue(jsonString, String[].class);
```

или

```
List<String> strings = mapper.readValue(jsonString,
    mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, String.class));
```